# Unclear how to implement weighted average of GoLive velocity data

Tags: landsat

I am trying to apply the weighed averaging scheme outlined in Scambos et al. 2007 to GoLive surface velocity data in Antarctica.

Essentially, for a given Landsat scene I have a number of ice velocity images, formed from image pairs spanning different intervals and dates. The goal is to stack and average colocated ice velocities. Fahnestock et al. (2016) defines a simple weighting scheme, but then states the weighted average is calculated according to the method outlined in Scambos et al. 2007.

This is where the confusion sets in, as I do not comprehend what the notation in Scambos et al. (2007) trying to convey in equation 7 in the attached screenshot. They write:

> "Images, or intermediate image composites, were added to create the final mosaic by the following scheme. Given two existing band 1 composites, B0 and B1, each having C0 and C1 count images and associated weight images W0 and W1, combined on them already, we create a new composite consisting of CN, WN, and BN

[image]

"

Can anyone elucidate the operation in equation seven for me (especially the meaning/utility of the semicolon)?